# Image not appearing when publicizing to facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I'm using WordPress and the problem I have is that I don't see any associated images being used when I paste a link into Facebook. Below is my Facebook OG:Data.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Plitvice Lakes National Park" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://nomadicnabeel.wordpress.com/2014/08/08/plitvice-lakes-national-park/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Since I watched the documentary of Plitvice Lakes National Park on BBC few years back, I knew I had to visit it at some point. From Split it was 3 to 4 hours drive. It was raining and I slept all t..." />
<meta property="article:published_time" content="2014-08-08T14:47:38+00:00" />
<meta property="article:modified_time" content="2014-08-08T14:47:38+00:00" />
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=589050513" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Nomadic Nabeel" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://wordpress.com/i/blank.jpg?m=1383295312g" />
```

Comment: Please note that your question has been edited to enable members of the community to provide better answers. W3D answer is spot on and you need to resolve the OG data. You will be using some kind of SEO plugin as that data is not default, so take a look at the plugin your using, I recommend Yoast SEO which.

Comment: I am not pasting the link directly into facebook. I am posting my blogpost via wordpress default editor with the "Publicize to Facebook" setting enabled

Comment: @nabeelfarid: It probably does not matter _how_ the link is being posted to Facebook. FB is probably scanning the source of the link for an `og:image` tag.

Comment: w3d is right, it uses the tag regardless how its been published, pasted or shared! og:image is the element that needs to be correct and since its using a blank.jpg image thats why its not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your open graph image tag references a blank image...

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://wordpress.com/i/blank.jpg?m=1383295312g" />
```

Comment: so how do i add the image link to this meta tag? I am simply posting my blogpost via wordpress default editor

Comment: Since the other "open graph" data would seem to be populated correctly, I would assume there is a missing field somewhere... or maybe it's because the single `img` in that article is hosted on another host (ie. Flickr) and whatever plugin you are using to populate this data is unable to fetch it (a guess)?

Answer (score 0):

The image used in http://wordpress.com/i/blank.jpg?m=1383295312g as property="og:image" is correctly big for Facebook, 200x200, but it is a blank white square, so iguess it is properly published, but you just don't see it. so w3d's answer is basically correct :)

Answer (score 0):

See link: [Custom Image Thumbnail while sharing URL on Facebook](http://technowide.net/2014/03/05/informational-custom-image-thumbnail-sharing-url-facebook/)

Use Facebook debugger: [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)