# Does an OG image must be present on a page for display in Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, open-graph-protocol, social-sharing-buttons

When sharing a link, a post or a tweet on a Facebook is it possible to set an image using OG meta tags that is not actually on the page you are sharing.

Example: You share `example.com/mypage.html` and has a img OG of `/example.png`

Does example.png actually have to be used on `mypage.html` to be displayed (as a thumbnail for example) on Facebook? Must `mypage.html` contain an <img> tag with a reference to this page? Is this mandatory?

Comment: This seems like an *very* simple thing to test :) But I'd go with yes. If you delete that image, it will be deleted from FB.

Comment: @Martijn: That does not appear to be the question. Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/70952/open-graph-protocol-what-to-do-when-an-image-doesnt-exist-on-the-page/70953

Comment: Make a page, add the OG tag but no images, click share. Now you know if it works and have an answer to te question.

Answer (score 1):

> Must mypage.html contain an  tag with a reference to this page?

No, the image does not need to be visible on the page you are linking to. The OG image represents/summarises the resource, it does not need to be part of its contents.

In this [related question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67869/image-not-appearing-when-publicizing-to-facebook/67871) the OP is advertantly linking to a (default) blank image on their WordPress blog (which doesn't appear on the page being linked to). Facebook is picking up the *blank* image.